# Why does this user have such low rep with so many good answers/questions?

Tags: support, reputation, users

Today on SO I saw a [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/259130/roman-a-taycher) with hundreds of good quality questions and answers, 34 badges, but only 69 rep.

So what could be going on here? Are there other reasons I'm not aware of, such as a way to sandbag your rep?

Comment: Show a link to that user

Comment: Which user? It's probably someone who as either a) given away their reputation in bounties or b) been hit with spam flags.

Comment: OK, I wasn't sure if it would be impolite to link to the user, so I deliberately left that out.  I'll edit one in.

Comment: And indeed: he offered a total of 2950 rep in bounties. That is about as much rep as I'd expect someone with those badges to have.

Comment: Thanks, I completely forgot about using your rep as currency for bounties and hadn't noticed that you could check out other users reputation history stats.  On unrelated note, is there something wrong with this question (it's been downvoted)?

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with your question. However, downvoting here at meta means someone disagrees with you but I don't know what's there to disagree here. The downvote could also have happened before you gave the link. Sometimes I have noticed that lack of details could lead to downvoting.

Comment: The downvote could simply mean `If you would have looked at his reputation graph/history you'd know`.

Comment: Well for a user much more experienced on SO, I'm sure it was obvious that you can look at another users reputation history.  For me, it was not so obvious to find the link to that feature.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The user in question has been very generous and given away 18 bounties worth 2950 points in total. See his [reputation stats](https://stackoverflow.com/users/259130/roman-a-taycher?tab=reputation) and the [bounty stats](https://stackoverflow.com/users/259130/roman-a-taycher?tab=bounties) for details.

That must be something of a record relative to total reputation!